# Изменение типа подлючения в ходе выполнения плейбука

Tags: ssh, ansible, devops, ssh-key

Плейбук начинается с ssh соединения по паролю.

Можно ли в ходе выполнения плейбука переключится на соединение по ключу, отправив публичный RSA и по завершению удалить его?

Плейбук содержит до 20 ролей выполнение которых через VPN занимает до 40 минут, подлючение по паролю это основной критерий текушей конфигурации инфроструктуры.

Сервера подготавливаются в офисе, где можно на время активировать ssh подлючение по ключу, что в свою очередь активирует pipelining (не доступный в режиме по паролю) дает прибавку в скорости до 40% на выполнение плейбука.

Comment: Удалить rsa pub key или auth по паролю?

Comment: @AfsmNGhr  удлить  ключ (обновил вопрос)

Comment: А разместить виртуалку в офисе, и пушить плейбуки туда - не вариант? Т.е. всё выполняться будет внутри локалки.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно менять тип подключения. Последним шагом нужно удалить pub key.

```
- name: Delete pub key
  authorized_key: 
    user: user 
    key: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}" 
    state: absent
  with_fileglob:
    - /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

При следующем подключении будет доступ только по паролю.

Comment: В ansible.cfg  плейбука указано использовать только подключение по паролю с его запросом, что приводит снижению скорости в виду не поддержке `pipelining` (отрывал кейс на GitHub по этому поводу, сказали нельзя...). Вот и думал можно ли варьировать тип подключения (пароль-ключ) в ходе отработки плейбука? Единственное, что пришло в голову сначала загнать ключ, потом изменить конфиг, и уж потом запускать основной плейбук.